# render php variable comming from database

Tags: php, mysql

what I want to do is want to save php variable in database (suppose {$baseUrl} ) and I am getting the data on php page with echo command and on the same page I have defined $baseUrl='/public'. I want to get the value for the base url but I'm getting simply  {$baseUrl} not '/public'

in db I have `<img src="{$baseUrl}/img.jpg" />`

on page I have

```
$baseUrl = "/public";
echo $content
```

it is giving `<img src="{$baseUrl}/img.jpg /">`

how can I get `<img src="/public/img.jpg" />`

Comment: Please show us some of your code.

Comment: really hard to guess what the question here is. More code needed, more infos needed

Comment: Please provide more info. Shouldn't you `<?php echo $baseUrl ?>` ?

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear here. `$content` comes from "db", i.e. from a database and is kind of a template, requiring `{$baseUrl}` to be replaced with something provided inside the script. And the question is, how.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is a string replace. The variable pointer ($baseUrl) is a string that comes from the database. If you echo it, it is still just a string. What you need to do is something like this:

```
<?php
  echo str_replace('$baseUrl', $baseUrl, $varFromDB); 
?>
```

Or do I understand your question wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Of course. Strings are strings, not PHP code. You'll have to replace it yourself, e.g.:

```
<?php

$baseUrl = '/public';
$string = '<img src="{$baseUrl}/img.jpg" />';

$replacements = array(
    '{$baseUrl}' => $baseUrl,
);

echo strtr($string, $replacements);
```

Comment: This is bad advise. Why not simply let PHP evaluate the variable by putting it between double quotes?

Comment: @Rijk - Because that's not how it works. Variable interpolation is performed on double-quoted strings parsed by the PHP interpreter, not in random strings coming from outside (e.g. a database). Try it yourself if you don't believe me. And I'm glad for that: it's one thing less to care about when reading external input (e.g. in `$_GET`).

Answer (score 1):

With

```
str_replace($content, '{$baseUrl}', $baseUrl)
```

.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `$baseUrl` variable to be evaluated? You have to put the variable outside of the string definition:

```
echo '<img src="' . $baseUrl . '/img.jpg" />';
```

or put it between double quotes (strings enclosed in double quotes are parsed by PHP):

```
echo "<img src=\"{$baseUrl}/img.jpg\" />";
```

Comment: how should he do that, when `$content` comes from a database?

Comment: php woun't parse it that way.. the best option is to use the str_replace($yourcontent, '{Old}', $new)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you need this solution:

```
$content = str_replace("{$baseUrl}", $baseUrl, $content);
```

Comment: "in db I have ..." -> `$content` seems to come from a database.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using the wrong quotes:

```
echo '<img src="{$baseURL}/img.jpg" />';
```

rather than

```
echo "<img src='{$baseURL}/img.jpg'/>";
```

Comment: "in db I have ..." -> `$content` seems to come from a database.

Comment: Sorry - re-read the question. `eval()` as mentioned by other posters would be the way to go. Possibly: `<?php eval ('echo "<img src=\'{$baseURL}/img.jpg\'/>"'); ?>`

Comment: I don't think so. `eval` opens a big security hole if you dn't know exactly what you do. And the OP mentions only this one variable which can be substituted, so `replace()` seems better to me. But YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use the eval() function...
This is not a good idea, but it would achieve what you want.

Comment: I don't think that's what he needs. He's obviously a beginner, so pointing him to use `eval()` without really knowing what he's doing is just creating a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Would have deserved a -1. But no downvote, because of mentioning that it is not a good idea.

Comment: I think `eval` is _exactly_ what the OP was after. Which is probably why it's best not to mention it at all.